# Google Pixel 7 losing debugging connection in wireless debugging, also "Allow USB debugging" keeps on popping up cable connection

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wireless, android-debugging

I have a **Google Pixel 7** which I'm using for Android app development.
I'm using it **on 2 PCs, in both environment the phone produces the very same errors:**

- When I connect it via USB cable it keeps popping up the "Allow USB debugging" dialog no matter that I check the "allow" checkbox. Sometimes it keeps popping up 3-4 times in a minute which also results in a lost connection making development impossible.
- QR code wireless pairing with Android Studio rarely works. Like 1-2 times from 10 tries, and it also loses connection in a few minutes. Same results with wireless connection using the "connect with code" option.

**Conculusions so far:**

- I experience all of the issues in both environment which makes me think the problem is not with the PCs and its softwares.
- The connection issues appear in both wireless and usb debugging which makes me think the phone itself has some built in error.

I tried all the solutions listed on other questions/answers in stackoverflow, also those issues are slightly different.

Please help if you can.

Comment: Apologies, when you say you've tried, you should list out what you have tried. When you say 2 different PCs, are they both Windows or Linux? Antivirus running? In a corporate environment with restrictions? Also using the same PC hardware using a different mobile device, are you having the same problem or everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has some problem for connecting devices through Wireless Debugging (QR code/Code pairing) which is evident on issue tracker page https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:824897&s=created_time:desc.

But regarding USB debugging, I would suggest you try a different cable, if that doesn't work, try using a different device.